# How do I check that a Gjs class has already been defined?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I am writing the preference view a GNOME shell extension and an facing issues when using the `imports.lang` function to write the application in an object oriented fashion.

```
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk
const Lang = imports.lang
Gtk.init(null)
const MyWindow = new Lang.Class({...})
```

Opening the preference window the first time works, but subsequent ones throw the following error: `Error: Type name Gjs_MyWindow is already registered`. Upon closing the window for the first time, I receive this error: `TypeError: prefsModule.init is not a function`.

The following more imperative code works:

```
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk
Gtk.init(null)
const window = new Gtk.Window({ type: Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL })
```

Based on the errors thrown, my guess is that the class is being redefined. How can I avoid redefinition and receive the defined class otherwise? (Are there any docs I can refer to?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the right answer is in [this discussion](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688973).

> If you extend a GObject class (anything from St, Clutter, Gtk, etc.), you're registering a new GType, and that's not possible for extensions.
>
> ...
>
> Extensions are dynamic modules, and they can be loaded and unloaded - but that's not at all possible for GTypes.

So, don't extend GTypes. Instead, use the "delegate pattern", which looks like that.

```
const Class = new Lang.Class({
  Name: "Class",

  _init: function() {
    this.actor = new St.Button();
  }
)};
```

This being said, if you have a look at the extensions installed on your system and do something like `grep -rn 'Extends: Gtk' /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`, you will see that some extensions still extend GTypes, and it doesn't cause any error. But you will notice that it's never done in the `extension.js` file...

Don't ask for more details here, that's all I know as of today !

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solid rundown of GObject/Gtk classes in GJS, checkout [testGObjectClass.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gjs/blob/master/installed-tests/js/testGObjectClass.js) and [testGtk.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gjs/blob/master/installed-tests/js/testGtk.js) (that whole directory is gold, actually).

If this is for `prefs.js`, you need a function called `buildPrefsWidget()` which should return a widget instance to be added to the window, not a Gtk.Window instance. Otherwise, you should define your class:

```
const MyWindow = new Lang.Class({
    Name: "MyWindow",
    Extends: Gtk.Window,

    _init: function (params) {
        this.parent(params);

        ...
    }
});
```

Then after defined, create an instance and use that:

```
Gtk.init(null);
let window = new MyWindow({ type: Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL });
window.show_all();
Gtk.main();
```